# Check df column containing list of values for the presence of at least n elements from each sublist of list in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a df containing a list in one column and I want to check if the column value contains at least one element from each sub-list in a list of list.

Example:

```
import pandas as pd
lstOflst = [['a', '5', '3', 'x'], ['1', 'e'], ['g', '7','x']]
data = [
    ['a', 'b', ['1','2','a'], '2d'],
    ['d', 'c', ['2','3','e'], '3b'],
    ['a', 'e', ['x','g','1'], '6a']
]
cols = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=cols)
```

I tried:

```
lst_set = set(lstOflst)
result = df[[len(lst_set.intersection(l.split()))>=1 for l in df['C']]]
```

It did not work out well throwing an error but I know its wrong. I am just not sure what to do next. This code was adopted from here: [Find rows in dataframe that must contain at least 2 elements from a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71974609/find-rows-in-dataframe-that-must-contain-at-least-2-elements-from-a-list) but it doesn't exactly help me.

Expected resulting dataframe should be:
`['a', 'e', ['x','g','1'], '6a']`
The result is because its column C values contains at least n = 1 element from each sub-list in my lstOflst. n can be any number not just 1

Comment: yes its by rows based on column C

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
# transform the list to sets, once, for efficiency
sets = [set(l) for l in lstOflst]
# [{'3', '5', 'a', 'x'}, {'1', 'e'}, {'7', 'g', 'x'}]

# for each list in "C", is there a non-null intersection for
# all the sets in "sets"?
mask = [all(S.intersection(l) for S in sets) for l in df['C']]
# [False, False, True]

df[mask]
```

output:

```
   A  B          C   D
2  a  e  [x, g, 1]  6a
```

*NB. as you want at least 1 element, there is no need to explicitly check for the length as any non-null intersection will be truthy. If you wanted an intersection of at least 2 items with each set however, you would need:*

```
N = 2
mask = [all(len(S.intersection(l))>=N for S in sets) for l in df['C']]
```

##### variant (see comments)

At least `N` items in common for any `M` sets:

```
mask = [sum(len(S.intersection(l))>=N for S in sets)>=M for l in df['C']]
```

Comment: retracted my comment. Its clearer now

Comment: Thanks @mozway . I am just trying to understand this. So how will this defer in the case where you want at least 2 occurencies in any 2 of the sublists?

Comment: for at least N items in common for any M sets: `mask = [sum(len(S.intersection(l))>=N for S in sets)>=M for l in df['C']]`